# Maven URL encoding issue

Tags: maven

When I set my `<url></url>` tag in the pom file as follow:

```
<url>http://test.io/pages/createpage.action?spaceKey=A&amp;fromPageId=B&amp;linkCreation=true&amp;labelsString=C&amp;title=D&amp;trash=</url>
```

I get the following error...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project plugin: Sit
eToolException: Error parsing site descriptor: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: TEXT seen .
..ref="http://test.io/pages/createpage.action?spaceKey=A&fromPageId=... @27:105) -> [Help 1]
```

By the error message, I assume that the parser starts with the `&` character and looks for the `;` to close the XML character (i.e. as in `&amp;`). Then it finds an `=` sign instead and fails.

However, I'm already providing the proper XML encoding in my pom file. So, am I missing anything here?

**EDIT:** Although it's explicit in the error message that I'm trying to execute the `site` goal, it may be important to mention that the current escaped URL works fine for generation of the effective POM. My issue is with the `site` goal only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your raw link (without escaped ampersands '*&*') inside:

```xml
<![CDATA[ url ]]>
```

SO that the resulting `<url>` element looks like:

```xml
<url><![CDATA[http://test.io/pages/createpage.action?spaceKey=A&fromPageId=B&linkCreation=true&labelsString=C&title=D&trash=]]></url>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I can see that the generated effective pom escapes the '&' properly with your change. But I still get the same error message for `mvn site`. Btw, the escaped version works fine to generate the effective pom. It fails for `site` only. Editing question.

Comment: if you are using nexus like repository for site please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102039/push-deploy-maven-project-to-nexus-3